# jquery $.post not working in some browsers

Tags: jquery, post

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#btnc").click(function(){
            $.post("php/snova_campanha.php", {campanha : $("#campanha").val() },
                function(data){
                    if(data == "1" )
                    {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                    else
                        alert(data);
                });
     });
});
```

the php only has:

```
<?php
echo 0;
return;
?>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="corpo" align="center">
    <br/><br/>
    <h1 align="center" style="color:#F8F8F8">Nova Campanha</h1>
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <form id="novacamp">
        <label style="color:#F8F8F8" for="campanha">Nome</label>
        <input align="middle" size="35" type="text" name="campanha" id="campanha"/>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" id="btnc" value="OK"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Im using this php just for tests, i will implement inserting into database, and returning 1 with sucess or 0.

Well, I have two pages, the other one is working fine:

WORKING LOGIN PAGES:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#login").click(function(){
        $("#login").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $.post("php/slogin.php", {usuario : $("#usuario").val(), senha : $("#senha").val()},
                function(data){
                    if(data != "1" && data != "0")
                    {
                        alert(data);
                        $("#login").removeAttr("disabled");
                    }
                    else
                        window.location = "principal.php";
                });
     });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="bar">
    <div id="container">
        <!-- Login Starts Here -->
        <div id="loginContainer">
            <img id="logoNetradio" src="../images/logonetradio3.png"/>
            <br/><br/><br/>
                <form id="formLogin">
                    <label for="usuario">Usuário</label>
                    <input align="middle" size="35" type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario"/>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <label for="senha">Senha</label>
                    <input align="middle" size="35" type="password" name="senha" id="senha" />
                    <br/>
                    <input type="submit" id="login" value="Login"/>
                </form>
        </div>
        <!-- Login Ends Here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I dont see any difference.........
When I run the non-working code, the address on my browsers changes to www.myaddress.com/current_page.php?campanha=value_on_textfield
seems like $.post is making a GET request on the current page...
Both codes works on IExplore
and the working pages works on chrome and IE but not on firefox....
Any ideas?

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Also, to test if the .post() is actually not working, you should put an alert(typeof data); as the first line in your callback function. And if you have firebug, it might be worth using console.log instead of alert.

Comment: if I add any alert(anything) on my callback method, it never shows up

Comment: The _proper_ way to toggle the disabled attribute is to call $("#login").prop("disabled", true); -- boolean attributes are supposed to use .prop() nowadays, as described in the jquery 1.6.1 changelog.

Comment: I have just open firebug and saw that the reqeust and response from php are just fine.......the callback function that is not beeing called

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4889/discussion-between-foxtrot-and-fredcrs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `return false` has some side effects in jQuery event handlers that most people aren't aware of. If all you want to do is prevent the form from submitting, then you should be using `event.preventDefault()`.

To make your life easier, I'd recommend changing your PHP file to return json, like so:

```
<?php
echo "{'status':'0'}";
?>
```

Then specify 'json' when performing the post:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#btnc").click(function(evt){
            $.post(
                "php/snova_campanha.php", 
                {campanha : $("#campanha").val() },
                function(data){
                   alert(data.status);
                },
                "json"
            );
            // Keep the form from submitting
            evt.preventDefault();
     });
});
```

Also, I will suggest looking into [malsup's excellent jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/), which takes care of the majority of what you're trying to do here.

Finally, you can try using the full `$.ajax` call instead of `$.post`:

```
$('#btnc').click(function(evt) {
   $.ajax({
       method: 'POST',
       url: 'php/snova_campanha.php',
       data: {
           campanha: $('#campanha').val()
       },
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data, status) {
           alert(data);
       },
       error: function(jqXHR, status, err) {
           alert('ERROR');
           alert(String(err));
       }
   });
   evt.preventDefault();
});
```

What's probably happening is that the `$.post` call is throwing an error. Using `$.ajax` as above will allow you to catch that error.

Comment: it is not performing the GET anymore, but the post still didnt do the post

Comment: great plugin, i will try it just now

Comment: I changed the code, opened firebug and saw the requisition and replies working, but the callback funcrion is not beeing called

Answer (score 0):

The `click` event of your button should return `false`, if the intent is to not allow the button to post the form.

Comment: I want the button to do the post request... I tryed to add 'return false' in the click event but it didnt work

Comment: @fredcrs are you sure the return was the last line of the callback? Return will stop execution of that function past that point.

Comment: @fredcrs No I don't think you understand. The button will run the $.post command you initiated, but the whole thing is inside a form which posts the form itself. And my answer is wrong... I forgot that as I don't use input[type=submit] when initiating an ajax command. Bryan Ross is correct in using event.preventDefault() to stop the form itself from being submitted.

Comment: ok I see. The request is doing fine, in firebug I recived the answer frm the PHP, now in JSON, like Bryan Ross told....but still the callback function is not beeing called...